# Accessing my application profile page

Tags: facebook

I'm getting a problem this morning with Facebook and a Facebook app.

I just finished the development of one of my application for a facebook fan page. I have created it on Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/) . Everything's fine, except that when I click on the "view my app profile page", Facebook redirects me to a page saying "You are being redirected to the (name of web app) web app". I have the choice between "Cancel" and "Go To App".

Clicking on "Go To App" will redirect me to the URL previously entered in the configuration (it goes out of Facebook) and not to the basic interface for Facebook apps.

My other apps do go to the correct application in Facebook but not the one of today...

There could be a problem in my app or is it related to Facebook ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [App Profile Page are not being created](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8447002/app-profile-page-are-not-being-created)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be related to this:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/

Specifically:

"New apps will not automatically get an App Profile Page. Instead, new apps can choose to create a Facebook Page from the Dev App. Simply visit the Contact Info section in the Advanced tab of the Dev App and click on the “Create Facebook Page” button to create a new Facebook Page."

Comment: Joe... If we create a facebook page for this app ("APPPAGE"), can we add the app to another fanpage ("MYFANPAGE") from this newly created page ("APPPAGE")? Damn... too much confusion