# how to make a redirect button app in facebook

Tags: facebook

the follow link is exactly i want to do
https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=80401312489

I've searched around on internet i didn't found any tutorial to do this simple app.

I've also read a similar post
[Accessing my application profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445203/accessing-my-application-profile-page)

but still no cues to do this. Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fill in the section

Website with Facebook Login

with your domain name.